# Python plotting graph, different regions setting colours differently

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, region

When I run my code it is returning a blank graph. I can't figure out why my code is doing this. I also need the graph when it is produced when ml <0 colour changes to blue. When ml>0 colour changes to a different colour and ml=0 another colour is produced. I will provide the code below. If someone could help this would be great as I am not very familiar with python.

```
(ax1) = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(8,9),
                              sharex=True)

#initial conditions                        
d= 0.1
eps = 0.000001

#defining the equations as functions
#xnew equation
def f(a,b,x,y):
z = 1-b*y
r  = a*x*z*(1-x*z)
if r>eps:
    return r
else:
    return 0

#ynew equation
def g(b,d,x,y):
    r = (1-d)*y*(1+b*x)
    if r>eps:
        return r
    else:
    return 0

#Equation A
def A(a,b,x,y):
    return a*(1-2*x - b*y + 4*b*x*y - 2*b**2*x*y**2)
#Equation B  
def B(b,a,x,y):
    return a*b*x*(2*x - 1 - 2*b*x*y)
 #Equation C   
def C(b,d,x,y):
    return (1-d)*b*y
#Equation D
def D(b,d,x,y):
    return (1-d)*(1+b*x)
#Equation E, which is max lyapunov exponent equation formed from the parameters above  
def e(a,b,x,y,yn):
    return log((A(a,b,x,y)+(B(b,a,x,y)*yn))**2 +(C(a,b,x,y)+ 
    (D(b,d,x,y)*yn))**2 / (1 + yn**2))
#next ydash value calculated after the max lyapunov exponent is calculated
def yz(a,b,x,y,yn):
    return (C(b,d,x,y)+(D(b,d,x,y)*yn))/(A(a,b,x,y)+(B(b,a,x,y)*yn))    
#defining the function
def lyapunov():
    #initial conditions
    d=0.1
    b=0.4
    xold = 0.5
    yold = 0.01
    #looping values of a and b 0<a<5 and 0<b<6
    for i in range(100):
        a = 1+ 4*i/100
        xold = 0.5
        yold = 0.01
        ydash = 1
        yn=1

        for i in range(100):
            b = 1+ 5*i/100
            xold = 0.5
            yold = 0.01  
            ydash = 1
            yn=1
            #looping round x and y values
            for j in range(100):
                xnew=f(a,b,xold,yold)
                ynew=g(b,d,xold,yold)
                ydash =1 
                #the new value of xnew is xold same for y
                xold = xnew
                yold = ynew
                #setting ml =0 as it starts at 0. inital
                ml = 0
                yn=1
                #calculating the two equations and plotting ml against a and
     #b. Also, need to print out the max ml value along with x and y        
     #value in a text file.

                for k in range(100):
                    outfile = open('lyapunov.txt', 'w')
                    #finding sum of max lyapunov exponent then * by 0.5*N, in this case N is 100
                    ml = e(a,b,xold,yold,yn)
                    ml = ml + e(a,b,xold,yold,yn)
                    ml = (ml/100)*2 
                    #ydash equation
                    ydash = yz(a,b,xold,yold,yn)
                    #now setting xold and yold equal to the equations xnew,ynew were so it keeps looping around each time, xold is no longer 0.5. Keeps taking new values. Same with yold.
                    xold=f(a,b,xold,yold)
                    yold=g(b,d,xold,yold)
                    #writing to file

                   outfile.write(str(xold)+'\t'+str(yolf)+'\t'+str(ml)+'\n')
    #plotting a,ml and b,ml            
    ax1.plot(a, ml,',k')
    ax1.plot(b, ml, ',k')
    #closing the file
    outfile.close() 
#setting graph axis             
ax1.set_ylim(0, 5)        
ax1.set_xlim(0, 6) 
#title
ax1.set_title('Lyapunov Exponent')  

lyapunov()
```

Comment: ```plt.subplots``` returns a ```figure``` and an ```axes``` instance. So to get started you probably want your first line to be ```fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(8,9), sharex=True)```

Comment: Ok so i have done this, Thank You! What else is needed to help me producing the graph with different coloured regions?